# How do you know if you can add 64 bit version of Lubuntu?

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit

NOOB alert-

I have an HP/Compaq nc6120 laptop. I just added the 32 bit version of Lubuntu, however I wondered what would tell me if I could use the 64 bit version? Here are my PC Specs

- Computer:

  - Processor        : Intel(R) Pentium(R) M processor 1.86GHz
  - Memory       : 2056MB (441MB used)
  - Operating System     : Ubuntu 13.10
- Display:

  - Resolution      : 1400x1050 pixels

I understand that PCs older than 2007 do not likely use 64 bit, but I'm not sure how old this laptop is.

Thanks for your help
Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intel Pentium M is a family of 32-bit processors, see [Pentium M on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_M).

So you cannot install Lubuntu 64-bit.